# How to limit the number of characters read by StreamReader.ReadLine() in .NET?

Tags: c#, readline, streamreader, ddos

I am writing a web server application in C# and using StreamReader class to read from an underlying NetworkStream:

```
 NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(clientSocket);
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
 String request = sr.ReadLine();
```

This code is prone to DoS attacks because if the attacker never disconnects we will never finish reading the line. Is there any way to limit the number of characters read by StreamReader.ReadLine() in .NET?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would have to use the `Read(char[], int, int)` overload (which does limit the length) and do your own end-of-line detection; shouldn't be too tricky.

For a slightly lazy version (that uses the single-characted reading version):

```
static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path, int maxLineLength)
{
    StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder(maxLineLength);
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        int i;
        while((i = reader.Read()) > 0) {
            char c = (char) i;
            if(c == '\r' || c == '\n') {
                yield return currentLine.ToString();
                currentLine.Length = 0;
                continue;
            }
            currentLine.Append((char)c);
            if (currentLine.Length > maxLineLength)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Max length exceeded");
            }
        }
        if (currentLine.Length > 0)
        {
            yield return currentLine.ToString();
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You might need one of `StreamReader.Read` overload:

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824.aspx

```
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
    {
        //This is an arbitrary size for this example.
        char[] c = null;

        while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
        {
            c = new char[5];
            sr.Read(c, 0, c.Length);
            //The output will look odd, because
            //only five characters are read at a time.
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }
```

Focus on the `sr.Read(c, 0, c.Length)` line. This reads only 5 character from stream and put in into `c` array. You may want to change 5 to value you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my own solution based on the solution by Marc Gravell:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProject
{
    class StreamReaderExt : StreamReader
    {

        public StreamReaderExt(Stream s, Encoding e) : base(s, e)
        {            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads a line of characters terminated by CR+LF from the current stream and returns the data as a string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="maxLineLength">Maximum allowed line length</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.IO.IOException" />
        /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">When string read by this method exceeds the maximum allowed line length</exception>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string ReadLineCRLF(int maxLineLength)
        {
            StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder(maxLineLength);

            int i;
            bool foundCR = false;
            bool readData = false;

            while ((i = Read()) > 0)
            {

                readData = true;

                char c = (char)i;

                if (foundCR)
                {
                    if (c == '\r')
                    {
                        // If CR was found before , and the next character is also CR,
                        // adding previously skipped CR to the result string
                        currentLine.Append('\r');
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (c == '\n')
                    {
                        // LF found, finished reading the string
                        return currentLine.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If CR was found before , but the next character is not LF,
                        // adding previously skipped CR to the result string
                        currentLine.Append('\r');
                        foundCR = false;
                    }
                }
                else // CR not found
                {
                    if (c == '\r')
                    {
                        foundCR = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                currentLine.Append((char)c);
                if (currentLine.Length > maxLineLength)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Max line length exceeded");
                }
            }

            if (foundCR)
            {
                // If CR was found before, and the end of the stream has been reached, appending the skipped CR character
                currentLine.Append('\r');
            }

            if (readData)
            {
                return currentLine.ToString();
            }

            // End of the stream reached
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

This piece of code is provided "AS IS" with NO WARRANTY.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use ".Read(...)" and MSDN recommends doing so for a situation like yours.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx